# "[Errno 13] Permission denied " while using dbt

Tags: cmd, google-bigquery, dbt

I am new to using dbt. I am trying to set up dbt on my windows 10 machine for local development purposes which later I will send the changes to the production environment. When I run `dbt debug`. The connection to Bigquery is not successful. If I check the logs am getting the following error

`BigQuery adapter: Got an error when attempting to create a bigquery client: '[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\path\\to\\my dbt installation''`

I have tried to run cmd as administartor as suggested on some other post but am still getting this error.

Please assit.Thanks